# Redis How to set "key name EXAT how_to_specify_format_unix_timestamp " in redis-cli

Tags: redis, unix-timestamp

I like to know how to specify unix-timestamp in redis.

for command like `SET name xyz EXAT 1617875638` //is wrong format cli says
On my terminal timestamp is something like this `1617875638`. this is exception causing. wrong format.

Answer (score 1):

`EXAT` option is added in Redis 6.2. If your Redis is older than 6.2, it cannot support it. Instead, you can use Lua script to implement it:

```
eval 'redis.call("set", KEYS[1], ARGV[1]); redis.call("expireat", KEYS[1], ARGV[2])' 1 name xyz 1617875638
```

Comment: U developed c++ client for redis. Is it raw socket tcp or stream socket.

Comment: Btw I am asking for 6.2

Comment: The client is based on hiredis, which uses a TCP connection, i.e. a TCP socket.